# AngularJs Bootstrap set dropdown item selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote this custom directive to intercept key events. Using the key pressed I check if there is an item inside the dropdown with the same first-letter character. Up to here all fine.

Next I want set the focus on this item, but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/dEqcMyLKLfsEccB6FS8y?p=preview

```
 myApp.directive('keypressEvents', 
 function ($document, $rootScope) {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        console.log('linked');

        $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        var target = e.target;

        var charat = element[0].textContent.charAt(13);
        if(element[0].tabIndex  === undefined)
        alert('undefined1');
        if(element.tabIndex  === undefined)
        alert('undefined2');
        if(element.focus === undefined)
        alert('undefined3');
        if(element[0].focus === undefined)
        alert('undefined4');
        if(charat === letter){ 
             alert(letter);        
             element[0].focus();     ////<<---- this dose not works
        }
        });
    }
};
});
```

The directive is bound to the `li` elements:

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
      <li  ng-repeat="v in values"  keypress-events >
        <a href="#">{{v.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if(charat === letter){ 

              element.addClass("active");
        }
        else{

              element.removeClass("active");
        }
```

simply this code in case the first letter match one in the menu 
set the css class to active, in other case remove the active.

Comment: A code block without any explanation attached usually doesn't help any future reader.  Try explaining what you're doing.

Comment: Dear @Daedalus you can read the question it is written a link to a code, if you read the code you find the statement with which i have answered

Comment: I have read the question; my point however is that a code-only answer, without any information aside from code, is frowned upon here.